# Can't get Paypal Sandbox to work

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have been searching for a solution for this really hard but I can't find any answers as to where the problem is really coming from have been setting up paypal sandbox account for testing but it doesn't work have been clearing my cache many times but still it returns me this error:

This Sandbox email address is not available. Please enter another email address.

I make sure the account I use is already set on sandbox and it's a personal account, please I need more help as to know where this problem is coming from, don't know what to do on this one anymore. also even deleting previous paypal sandbox account doesn't even work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one possibility.  I was running into that same error just a couple of days ago and realized what it was.

I have 2 separate PayPal accounts that are setup with developer.paypal.com.  They each have 3 or 4 sandbox accounts created within them.

I had just recently been to developer.paypal.com and logged in with one of my PayPal accounts, so that session was active in my browser.  Then I was trying to complete a sandbox checkout using one of the sandbox accounts associated with my other PayPal account, and that's when I was getting that error that the email address was not available.

I went back to developer.paypal.com and logged out of the account I had signed in there, and then specifically logged in with the other account that was associated with the sandbox account I was trying to use.  Once I did that the error went away and I was able to use the sandbox as expected.

Hope all that made sense.  Just a shot in the dark as it's the only time I've seen this error myself.